# Rrearrange order of column by columns name

Tags: sql, sas, proc

I have dataset like follows;

```
data dataset;
input name $ mob5 mob1 mob3 x;
datalines;
a 1 3 5 7
b 2 4 6 8
c 3 5 7 9 
d 5 7 9 2
;

run;
```

I would like to select the fields name and those with mob (UNKNOW columns name and number of columns contain mob). i dunno how to use retain i do not know how many of columns with columns name contains mob.

```
proc sql;
    create table table1 as
    select *
    from dataset(keep=name mob:)
quit;
```

My desired output will be

```
name mob1 mob3 mob5
a 3 5 1
b 4 6 2
c 5 7 3
d 7 9 5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the dictionary tables for this (assuming your source dataset is called 'dataset' and resides in the work library, make changes to the `WHERE` clause if not, but make sure you use upper-case for the values):

```
PROC SQL;
  SELECT name INTO: mob_cols SEPARATED BY ','
  FROM dictionary.columns
  WHERE libname = 'WORK' and memname = 'DATASET' 
  AND upcase(name) LIKE 'MOB%'
  ORDER BY name;
QUIT;
```

This code loads all of the 'mob' columns into a macro variable, ordered by name and separated by comma.

Then you can use this macro variable in the `SELECT` clause of your `PROC SQL`:

```
PROC SQL;
  CREATE TABLE table1 AS
  SELECT name,
  &mob_cols.
  FROM dataset;
QUIT;
```